# objFile.Write(Now) invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: vbscript

I am getting error like "Line 10 and Char 2. invalid procedure call or argument" i run below VBS

Line 10 and Char 2.

```
Const ForAppending = 8
Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
GetLogPath = "C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\New Text Document.log"
If objFSO.FileExists(GetLogPath) Then
    set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(GetLogPath)
else
    set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(GetLogPath)
End If
set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(GetLogPath , ForAppending)
    objFile.Write(FormatDateTime(Now))
    objFile.WriteLine(" : ")
    objFile.Close
```

My System date and time settings as below.

[Bulgaria Date and Time settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIsE9.jpg)

But When i ran same script in other PC and working fine which contain English language date and Time settings.

<**OutPut**>9/13/2017 5:44:15 PM :

Could you please help on this case.

Comment: Why do you even need `FormatDateTime`? Have you tried writing `Now` as is in the file?

Comment: Yes, I have tried  with "objFile.Write Now" and "objFile.Write(Now)". and i observed same issue for all date and time functions like Date,Day...... [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_vbscript_functions.asp)

Comment: I have read somewhere that VBScript may run into problems for non English locales ... try manually formatting the date and time functions by concatenating datepart function such as Day, Month and Year

Comment: Think I have found the link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/264063/vbscript-date-and-time-functions-may-not-be-formatted-properly-in-non

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gurman Thanks for your valuable solution. Some how I am not able to implement your solution. So I have written below function (`Function GetNow()`) to achieve my requirement.

```
Const ForAppending = 8
strComputer = "."
Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
GetLogPath = "C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\New Text Document.log"
If objFSO.FileExists(GetLogPath) Then
    set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(GetLogPath)
else
    set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(GetLogPath)
End If
set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(GetLogPath , ForAppending)
    objFile.Write(GetNow)
    objFile.WriteLine(" : ")
    objFile.Close

Function GetNow()

Set objWMIServiceNow = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIServiceNow.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")

For Each objItem in colItems
   dtmLocalTime = objItem.LocalDateTime
   dtmMonth = Mid(dtmLocalTime, 5, 2)
   dtmDay = Mid(dtmLocalTime, 7, 2)
   dtmYear = Left(dtmLocalTime, 4)
   dtmHour = Mid(dtmLocalTime, 9, 2)
   dtmMinutes = Mid(dtmLocalTime, 11, 2)
   dtmSeconds = Mid(dtmLocalTime, 13, 2)
Next

GetNow = dtmMonth & "/" & dtmDay & "/" & dtmYear & " [" & dtmHour & ":" & dtmMinutes & ":" & dtmSeconds & "]"

End Function
```

Thanks to all for your time and support :)

Ramesh

Answer (score 1):

**REASON FOR ERROR: INCORRECT ENCODING FORMATS**

You are getting the error because the text which you are trying to write to the text file is in Bulgarian language whereas your text file's encoding is ANSI(see the image) **by default**. The solution is to save your file in a universal encoding, either **Unicode or UTF-8**. These encodings map the Bulgarian characters to the Unicode standard. You will have to open/create your log file in Unicode format to be able to write Bulgarian characters.

**Tested Code:**

```
Const ForAppending = 8
Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
GetLogPath = "C:\Users\Kira\Desktop\url.log"

'The entire If condition of your code can be replaced with the following line of code:
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(GetLogPath,ForAppending,True,-1)      'The 3rd parameter "True" is for creating the textfile if the textfile is already not created and the 4th parameter  is for specifying the Encoding format. -1 means Unicode; for ANSI, leave the last param blank.

objFile.Write(FormatDateTime(Now))
objFile.WriteLine(" : ")
objFile.Close
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

For more help, click [HERE](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2006/04/19/how-can-i-open-a-text-file-as-unicode/)

**ENCODING FORMATS:**

[image: Encoding]

Comment: The comment and the link refer to the CreateTextFile method; the code uses OpenTextFile. The 4th arg of OpenTextFile is *not* Boolean, but TriState.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner My bad. I have updated the link and solution